# Doctrine 2 inheritance mapping: can NULL be used as a discriminator?

Tags: php, inheritance, orm, doctrine-orm

I have the following hierarchy of classes:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"root" = "RootCategory", "sub" = "SubCategory"})
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class RootCategory extends Category
{
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class SubCategory extends Category
{

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="RootCategory")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parent;
}
```

In this domain model, we have only two possible levels in the hierarchy, hence the distinction as `RootCategory` or `SubCategory`.

I find it redundant to have to specify an explicit *discriminator column*, where we could just use a simple rule as the discriminator:

- If `parentId` is *null*, then this is a `RootCategory`
- If `parentId` is *not null*, then this is a `SubCategory`

Is it possible with **Doctrine 2**, to use the NULL status of a column as the discriminator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

If you look at the [source code of Doctrine 2](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/SingleTablePersister.php) you will see that he transforms `DiscriminatorMap` into array, that can't have NULL key, only string or integer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the following in DQL

`$qb->where('{...} IS NULL');`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I'm not trying to query an entity against a NULL value, but use a NULL value as the discriminator in an inheritance mapping so that Doctrine knows which class in a hierarchy to instantiate!